# Quasar QSpinner module not found

Tags: quasar, quasar-framework

Im getting the following error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                                       

This relative module was not found:

* ./QSpinner in ./node_modules/quasar-framework/src/components/spinner/index.js
```

Ive tried reinstalling quasar-cli and updating npm

im working with  quasar-framework                      0.15.8
and quasar-cli                            0.15.12

Comment: if you are using quasar old version, you have to use spinner following this documentation: http://v0-13.quasar-framework.org/components/spinners.html. And for new version of quasar, documentation is: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/spinners

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you include QSpinner component.
Open quasar.conf.js file and look for framework components and add it there.

```
framework: {
  components: [
    'QSpinner',
    'QLayout',
    'QLayoutHeader',
    'QLayoutDrawer',
    'QPageContainer',
    'QPage',
    'QToolbar',
    'QToolbarTitle',
    'QBtn',
    'QIcon',
    'QList',
    'QListHeader',
    'QItem',
    'QItemMain',
    'QItemSide'
  ],
  directives: [
    'Ripple',
    'TouchPan'
  ],
  // Quasar plugins
  plugins: [
    'Notify'
  ]
},
```

If you already did so, try deleting node_modules and re-run 'npm install'

Answer (score 2):

All of the quasar modules that you use in your project will be enabled if you set the all quasar.conf setting to "auto."
***all*** to **'*auto*'**

```html
    framework: {
      iconSet: 'material-icons', // Quasar icon set
      lang: 'en-us', // Quasar language pack

      // Possible values for "all":
      // * 'auto' - Auto-import needed Quasar components & directives
      //            (slightly higher compile time; next to minimum bundle size; most convenient)
      // * false  - Manually specify what to import
      //            (fastest compile time; minimum bundle size; most tedious)
      // * true   - Import everything from Quasar
      //            (not treeshaking Quasar; biggest bundle size; convenient)
      all: 'auto',

      components: [],
      directives: [
        'GoBack'
      ],

      // Quasar plugins
      plugins: [
        'Loading',
        'LocalStorage',
        'SessionStorage',
        'Notify'
      ]
    },
```

So when you set property **'all' to 'auto'**, that means Auto-import needed Quasar components & directives

Answer (score 0):

Include QSpinner component in quasar.conf.js file and look for framework components and in root  directory there is a .quasar folder, inside it there are file import-quasar.js and quasar.js.

```
 Vue.use(Quasar, {components: {QSpinner,QPagination,QChatMessage,QScrollArea,...
```

also import component at the beginning